# Ember Component handle jQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In an Ember app Component, what is the best hook within which to handle jQuery event handlers ?
I want to handle a keyUp event on an input element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`didInsertElement` would be the best place to do anything `jquery` or `dom` related operation.

> didInsertElement() is also a good place to attach event listeners. This is particularly useful for custom events or other browser events which do not have a built-in event handler.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code

***Edit***

We do not need `$(document).ready()` since document would have already been loaded by that time. You can access the dom element globally or locally.

You can access globally by using `Ember.$()` which is a similar to normal query which you can use to select any element on the page. Even from another component.

The better (preferred) approach is to access locally using `this.$()` which is scoped to component elements only.

For example:

```
<h1 class="title">Heading 1</h1>
{{your-component}}

# your-component.hbs
<div> <h2>Component Heading 2</h2></div>
```

From above example, you can access both  and  tags inside `didInsertElement` globally by using `Ember.$('h1')` and `Ember.$('h2')`

However if you do `this.$('h1')`, it will return `null` as your component template does not have h1 tag and the exiting h1 tag is outside of your component.

In nutshell, `Ember.$()` acts like regular `$()` and `this.$()` act like `Ember.$('your component root element').find()`

Comment: Thx...Would the handler have to be written in $(document).ready() or that is assured by the hook...And would $("#id") give me the DOM element ?

Comment: Awesome..Thanks for that detailed response !!

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but I don't see why there is any need to register an event handler via jQuery. `Component.exend({ keyUp() { ... } })` seems to be fine and way more easy cause you don't have to deal with runloop.